# Disable URL menu in ubuntu

Tags: gnome

ubuntu 18.04
I'm trying to copy any URL in browser and can't do it couse get this menu. It's block Ctrl+C to copy into the buffer. I need to press esc every time to disapper this menu.

Same behavor in browsers (firefox, chrome) and in the Thunderbird app.

How to disable this menu appearence?
[image]

Comment: Which desktop are you using?

Comment: neofetch DE: GNOME 3.28.4

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: it's not GNOME. It's Cairo-Dock app.

1. plugin Clipper ~/.config/cairo-dock/current_theme/plug-ins/Clipper/Clipper.conf set to false property: enable actions=false
2. Restart cairo-dock

Comment: 1. plugin Clipper  ~/.config/cairo-dock/current_theme/plug-ins/Clipper/Clipper.conf set to false property: enable actions=false  2. Restart cairo-dock

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Better to edit the answer and add imported instruction there. Comments get deleted  usually.